# Multiply matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

that's the first question I upload so please be proud of me and forgive me if I do something wrong in the post.
well I'm using numpy but I want it to multiply an array of dimensions A (k, n) * B (m, k) which is mathematically correct. I understand that the matrix to be multiply must be A (n, k) * B (k, m).
but the question is how can I multiply this matrix without using this code that I look like in some places where is used 3 "for", and I also want to know why I can't multiply this matrix.

```
import numpy as np
a= np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
print(a.shape[0])
print(b.shape[1])
print(a@b)
print(a@b)
ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 2 is different from 3)
```

Comment: `a@b.T` or `b@a` will run

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

```
>>> a= np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]])
>>> print(a)
[[1 2 3]
[2 3 4]
[7 8 9]]
>>> b = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
>>> print(b)
[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

As you can observe, a is (3x3) and b is (2x3). It is not possible to multiply these two because you can only multiply two matrices if their dimensions are compatible, which means the number of columns in the first matrix is the same as the number of rows in the second matrix.

We can change the dimensions of b to be (3x2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a= np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[7,8,9]])
>>> b = np.array([[1,2],[3,2],[3,4]])
>>> print(a@b)
[[16 18]
 [23 26]
 [58 66]]
```

Comment: many thanks sorry i forget that in linear algebra the mult matrix is defined like A(m,k) * B(k,n)  = C(m,n)